# Using a Rails Each.do inside of Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, I'm trying to show all the users who liked a post in a twitter tooltip (sort of like facebook i guess).

The ruby code to get all of the users is

```
<% product_feed_item.voters_who_voted.each do |voter| %>
  <%= voter.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

And Here is my tooltip code

```
<%= link_to likes_path(product_feed_item.collection, product_feed_item), class: "tooltip", :title => "", :"data-toggle" => "tooltip", :"data-placement" => "top", :'data-original-title' => " (NEEDS RUBY CODE FROM ABOVE" do %>
  Link
<% end %>
```

I just don't know the proper way to put that block of ruby code inside of the data-original-title part of the tooltip. If anyone can help me out it's greatly appreciate. I think I provided all of the code you should need but if I can provide any more please let me know.

Thanks in advance. Happy Holidays and War Eagle!

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to likes_path(product_feed_item.collection, product_feed_item), class: "tooltip", :title => "", :"data-toggle" => "tooltip", :"data-placement" => "top", :'data-original-title' => product_feed_item.voters_who_voted.map(&:full_name).to_sencence do %>
  Link
<% end %>
```

However, it's definitely a bad practice to write all that Ruby code in a view and definitely a bad practice to chain all such Ruby methods altogether.

I encourage you to refactor the code using Helpers and/or write some custom method in the ProductFeeditem class such as `ProductFeeditem.voters_names`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve exactly what you've asked for, try this:

```
<%= link_to likes_path(product_feed_item.collection, product_feed_item), class: "tooltip", :title => "", :"data-toggle" => "tooltip", :"data-placement" => "top", :'data-original-title' => product_feed_item.voters_who_voted.map(&:full_name).to_sentence do %>
  Link
<% end %>
```

Or to be more idiomatic, create a helper that returns a humanized list of voters' names.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes. I'm relatively new to Programming so it's always nice to learn something on S.O.